# How do I create a new empty file in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, files

I'm running some third-party Perl script written such that it requires an output file for the output flag, `-o`.

Unfortunately, the script appears to require an actual file, that is, users must create an empty file `filename.txt` with 0 bytes and then input this empty file on the script command line

```
perl script1.pl -o filename.txt
```

Question: How would I create an empty file within a bash script? If one simply tries `perl script1.pl -o filename.txt`, the script gives an error that the file doesn't exist.

Comment: `touch filename.txt`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a simple .txt (text) file using terminal?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159672)

Comment: see also [Why isn't there any shell command to create files?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/124081)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use `touch` command. `touch filename.txt`.

Comment: `echo -n >file`

Comment: take care - this will not empty your file if it already exists

Comment: Actually I tried touch and "echo -n > file" inside my bash script but I get an error when I execute the script: "No such file or directory" on that line.  Can someone help please?

Comment: ```echo -n "" > filename``` will empty the file if it exists or creates a file if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 15):

The shortest way:

```
>filename
```

Comment: Best answer. Couldn't be shorter.

Comment: Could you provide a reference to an explanation, please?

Comment: it's related to [redirecting output](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirecting-Output) on **bash** ‣ `[n]>[|]word`

Answer (score 12):

Use the null command (`:`) redirect (`> filename`) trick (`:>`), as this will truncate to zero or create the named file.

```
$ echo foo > filea
$ :> filea
$ wc -c filea
       0 filea
$ rm filea
$ :> filea
$ wc -c filea
       0 filea
```

(This will fail if the shell sets a NOCLOBBER option.)

Comment: If noclobber is set, use the redirection `>|` to clobber, so `:>| filea` -- documented [in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirecting-Output)

Comment: Just `> filename.txt` would do, no need for the `:`. Or `>> filename.txt` if we don't want to trash it if it does happen to exist.

Comment: @ilkkachu although the question does specify Bash, using `:` does make the script more likely to accomplish its task with other shells e.g. Zsh.

Answer (score 3):

You could always use perl, too.

```
$ stat filename.txt
stat: cannot stat 'filename.txt': No such file or directory
$ perl -e 'open($fh,">","filename.txt") or die $!;close($fh)'                                         
$ stat filename.txt                                                                                   
  File: 'filename.txt'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 280728      Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ xieerqi)   Gid: ( 1000/ xieerqi)
Access: 2017-02-08 13:51:01.479121995 -0700
Modify: 2017-02-08 13:51:01.479121995 -0700
Change: 2017-02-08 13:51:01.479121995 -0700
 Birth: -
```

Answer (score 1):

`dd` can be used to create an empty file as follows:

```
dd if=/dev/null of=filename.txt count=0
```

One case where `dd` is more useful than the other approaches is creating an EFI variable (PK) through the `efivars` filesystem (`/sys/firmware/efi/efivars`).

One some platforms and Linux distributions, the file is created with the "`immutible`" attribute set (shows up as the "`i`" flag with "`lasattr`"). So, any subsequent operations on the file fail.

For example, `touch` not only creates the file, but sets the time stamp on the file. Similarly, piping to the file with `>` not only creates the file, but performs additional operations that fail. The `dd` command does not appear to fail the same way.