# Creating a file in Linux? (Touch vs Echo)

Tags: linux, files, echo, touch

I'm pretty new to Linux in general, so I'm not too familiar with do's and don'ts of some commands.

I wanted to create a file and noticed that:

```
touch file.txt `
```

creates a file, but so does:

```
echo >> file.txt
```

and also

```
> file.txt
```

The files created with ">" and "touch" are both 0 bytes but the file created with "echo" is 1 byte.

Why are the files different sizes and what's the best way to create a file? When should someone create a file with "echo" instead of "touch" or ">"?

Answer (score 5):

For the general question about creating files, see: [Why isn't there any shell command to create files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/124081/70524)

---

With both `> file` and `echo >> file`, the **shell** creates the file if it didn't already exist.

With `> file`, the file is truncated if it already existed.  No command was specified, so nothing gets written to the file and the file will be empty.

`echo`, without any arguments, prints an empty line. So the output contains the line ending character, typically linefeed (LF, `\n`):

```
% echo | od -c
0000000  \n
0000001
```

So with `echo >> file`, you get one byte written to the file. If the file already existed, then it would have one byte added to it, because you used `>>` (append) instead of `>` (overwrite).

`touch` creates a file if it didn't already exist, and updates the timestamps on it otherwise. `touch` doesn't change the contents of the file, so if it already existed and had some contents in it, the contents would remain the same after `touch`.

Which you want to use depends on what effect you want.

Answer (score 1):

[muru's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/530560/29483) nicely explains the differences in behaviour.

Depending on what you want, there could be multiple ways to achieve the exact same thing.  In that case it can be a matter of "taste", or readability.  I prefer `touch`.  It is arguably safer - in case the file already exists, and you did not want to lose its contents.  It is also memorable.

If you are writing commands in a script, the general rule is that people read code more times than you write it.  I.e. you are communicating with humans - including your future self - and not just the computer :-).  You might find the following line of code a bit non-obvious.

```
> file
```

If you need the exact same behaviour as `> file`, there is also a command named  `truncate`.  `truncate` is provided by GNU coreutils.